# Postback occurs even on Not Page.IsValid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a form that is called by Ajax inside a div on a site I'm building. When I try to trigger my forms validation it validates as asked but still causes postback which leaves my Ajax-page to reload as an ordinary page in my browser. Basically what I want to do is leave it inside the div with the validation text visible next to the form (just as any ordinary server-side validation would do).

There is nothing wrong with the validation - it validates as it should. There's nothing wrong with my Ajax either as the form displays correct before validation. I just want the postback to halt until the form validates.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I removed tons of code from this question due to me finding the cause of the error. I have isolated it to these lines (commenting the if-clause out removes the problem):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        btnPublishFeedback.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.value = 'Sparar synpunkten...';this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnPublishFeedback, Nothing) + ";")
    End If
End Sub
```

Why do these lines kill the halt?

Comment: Please post your corresponding code ...

Comment: check you have any java script errors after load the page

Comment: I will post my code as soon as I get home from work. I don't think JavaScript is the cause of this error since there's no client side validation related to the form. I believe the problem is connected to the page life cycle though I cannot grasp where the error occurs.

Comment: The error is likely with where / how you're checking the validation at the server.  But, as GGG said, it would be good to see your code to confirm this.

Comment: _"there is no client side validation"_ - unclear on this statement, if there is no client side validation, then validation is on postack/server side.

Comment: Well actually it is client side validation but the ones built in the .NET framework. What I should had said is that I haven't build any custom validation using JavaScript. Thanks for pointing out the need of clarification. ;)

Comment: @GGG I added the coding you asked for. I hope you find something I don't. :)